# Catch an event raised from the Shared DLL but in a different project

Tags: c#, dll, event-handling

I am trying to catch an event raised from the Shared DLL but in a different project

To explain more , I have got a Dll lets say "Common" which I am using in two separate projects. How Can I raise Events from My Library

In my Common DLL, I have a class A

```
public class MyCustomEvent : System.EventArgs
{
     public string MyStatement;
}

public class A 
{
    public delegate void MyCustomEventHandler(object sender, MyCustomEvent e);
    public EventHandler<MyCustomEvent> RaiseEvent;

    public void DoSomeStuff()
    {
        var args = new MyCustomEvent { MyStatement = "ha ha ha" };
        if(RaiseEvent != null) // This is always Null
        {
             RaiseEvent(this, args);
        }
    }
};
```

I am using this DLL in a Winforms application & on a button click it is raising this event , Say like this.

```
 private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
    A a = new A();
    a.DoSomeStuff();
 }
```

Now, the same DLL is used in Different Project, where I have subscribed to this event handler

```
public class B 
{
  A aObj = new A();

  public B()
  {
    aObj.MyCustomEvent += CatchEvent;
  }

  private void CatchEvent(object sender, MyCustomEvent myEvent)
  {
    if (myEvent != null)
        {
            String str = myEvent.MyStatement;
        }
  }
}
```

But while raising Event only, My event is always null as if no one is subscribed to that handler.

Comment: Have you create an instance of `B`? Without instantiating `B` no one will subscribe to event.

Comment: @Sintar, Yes, I have

Comment: Oh, I see you are rising event on instance of `A`, while `B` uses **another instance**. Define event as `static` if you want to share it between instances.

Comment: Can you please share some source code how to do that.

Comment: `aObj.MyCustomEvent += CatchEvent` doesn't makes sense for me. Event is called `RaiseEvent`. Typo while copy/paste?

Comment: @Sinatr, yeah, it has to be aObj.RaiseEvent

Comment: Then simply add `static` to `RaiseEvent` declaration (in class `A` of common.dll). If you don't like idea with making event static, then you have to use *same instance* of `A` to rise and recieve events. Notice you have twice `new A()` in your code. This instantiation should happens only once. Either button click handler or your `B` class should use **already created instance of A** instead of creating another one.

Comment: I made my RaiseEvent as static as sunscribed like this A.RaiseEvent += CatchEvent; but still no luck :(

Comment: It appears I misunderstood (completely) your intentions. It's impossible to achieve that what you want, because *same* dll will be in different context for different exe-files (read - no shared data). You have to use IPC to pass/synchronize data. To example, library itself can be server and client, which context runs first will create a server. Then second exe-file will cause dll to connect to itself and start passing data. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102.aspx), I don't think I can help you much with it.